# Best way of adding two lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two list

```
list1 = [(100, A, 22), (200,B, 33), (300, C, 44)]
```

and

```
list2 = [(100,A,333), (200,B,444), (500, D, 555)]
```

so what I want as my final list is

```
final_list = [ (100,A, 22, 333), (200,B,33,444), (300,C,44,0), (500,D,0,555)]
```

If I just add the two list it wont help me out. How can i achieve the final list.

Thanks

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a `list` as a variable name when it is also a keyword.

Comment: @Hooked: `list` is not a [keyword](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).  It's a bad idea to use it as an identifier anyway since it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I didn't realize the distinction until you pointed that out. I assumed that python let you assign a variable to any reserved word (and I wrongly assumed that the built-in types belonged to that group). So it seems you can have a `set` and `list` variable but not a `for` or `yield`. Do you know what the rationale behind that is?

Comment: @Hooked: Keywords are part of the syntax, while built-in names are syntactically equivalent to user-defined names.  The parser does not need to treat `list` any different than the user-defined name `x` -- it's just a name.  In contrast, the parser *does* need to treat `for` and `yield` differently.  Built-in names and keywords are very different things.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That makes sense! The parser has to determine the order of execution, and keywords affect that, but a type is a type regardless of who made it. I guess my confusion came from my C background where a built-in type like `int` _is_ a keyword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input data should be dictionaries in the first place:

```
dict1 = {(100, "A"): 22, (200,"B"): 33, (300, "C"): 44}
dict2 = {(100, "A"): 333, (200,"B"): 444, (500, "D"): 555}
```

Now you can easily build a combined dict:

```
>>> {k: (dict1.get(k, 0), dict2.get(k, 0))
...  for k in dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys()}
{(100, 'A'): (22, 333), (200, 'B'): (33, 444), 
 (300, 'C'): (44, 0), (500, 'D'): (0, 555)}
```

(Python 2.7)

If for some reason you need to operate on the lists, I'd suggest turning your lists into dictionaries first

```
dict1 = {(k1, k2): v for k1, k2, v in list1}
dict2 = {(k1, k2): v for k1, k2, v in list2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that A, B, C, D, etc. are immutable objects, the easiest way would be:

```
[list(set(x) | set(y)) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: You might want to try this out first.

Comment: learning_python : can you explain what is exactly going on here ?